# IOS Change Round Button Background Color from Center To Edge

Tags: ios, uibutton

How can I change a round button background color gradually from center to edge or from edge to center? 
A code example would be truly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to figure it out on your own first, then come back with problems you have.

Comment: Can you give a hint?

Comment: This sounds like a legitimate case for a custom `UIView` subclass that overrides `drawRect:` with custom drawing code.